# Multiple where clause failed

Tags: android, database

In my code I have a database and when I retrieve rows with `KEY_DESC = userselectvalue` , it worked. But when I tried to retrieve rows with multiple 'where' conditions it failed. I used to show the retrieved elements in `ListView`. Please help me. No errors are showing. But the `ListView` is blank.

```
 public Cursor fetchEventByName(String inputText,String inputText1) throws SQLException {
        //Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if ((inputText == null || inputText.length () == 0) && (inputText1 == null || inputText1.length () == 0 ) ){
        mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_EVENT, KEY_DATE },
        null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else {

            String [] temp = new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_DESC, KEY_EVENT, KEY_DATE};
        mCursor = db.query(false,DATABASE_TABLE,temp ,
                KEY_DESC + " = '" + inputText + "'" + " AND " + KEY_DATE + " = '" + inputText1+ "'", null, null, null, null, null);


        }

        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
   }
```

Comment: Your values in the table don't match the criteria for KEY_DESC and KEY_DATE. Can you post the content of the table and the content of inputText and inputText1?

Answer (score 0):

You could try db.rawQuery by passing sql queries directly.